# Building an image and getting ERROR [4/6] COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Tags: php, docker, apache, xampp

I'm trying to run and build an image on docker, but once I try to build it, I get an error saying

> ERROR [4/6] COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf                              0.0s

II have xampp and php installed, but am I missing anything? it looks to me like apache is missing a file or something, but I've no clue, any help would be appreciated!

```
C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Github\project\.docker>docker build --tag my-project .
[+] Building 0.8s (8/10)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:7.4.1-apache                                                0.7s
 => CANCELED [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/php:7.4.1-apache@sha256:adeca522dc9cc66693e89ce95dc1a9480dc00bdc4e3b6ca  0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/php:7.4.1-apache@sha256:adeca522dc9cc66693e89ce95dc1a9480dc00bdc4e3b6caecffed13e  0.0s
 => => sha256:adeca522dc9cc66693e89ce95dc1a9480dc00bdc4e3b6caecffed13e2600296d 1.43kB / 1.43kB                     0.0s
 => => sha256:0c37fe4343a5fef4328a6b80cb8bfe8bb173e60cdbd7615197cb16b8a84161ed 13.15kB / 13.15kB                   0.0s
 => => sha256:82e8981b747bfd2f3249370a7cbea49e3397e30442bf84229859e87649c5a4a8 3.04kB / 3.04kB                     0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /var/www/html                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [3/6] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y         libpng-dev         zlib1g-dev         libxml2-d  0.0s
 => ERROR [4/6] COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf                              0.0s
[4/6] COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

------
 [4/6] COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:
------
failed to compute cache key: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount569533998/.docker: lstat 
/var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount569533998/.docker: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Looks like a bogus path to me, you are in `C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Github\project\.docker` and your context is `.`, then you try to copy the file `.docker/vhost.conf`. Unless you have a folder `.docker` in a folder `.docker`, like so: `C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Github\project\.docker\.docker`, I'd expect your instruction to rather be `COPY vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

Comment: You were completely right by the way! wish I could upvote your answer